# Is there a way to access AWS resources with Access KeyID and Secret Key stored in parameter store?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I currently have a python utility running on my laptop that connects to AWS resources using Access keyID and Secret Access key from an IAM user that I have provisioned. In the current method I am hard coding the Access Key and Secret Key in the utility to establish a session using boto3 and connect to the Database.

```
        session = boto3.session.Session( 
                        aws_access_key_id='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'
                       ,aws_secret_access_key='ZYXWVUTSRNMPOQ12345678')
        client = session.client('rds', region_name=us-east-1)
```

Now I have saved the specific Access Key and Secret Key in AWS parameter store but I am trying to see if there is a way to retrieve from that so I dont have to hard code the Access key and secret key ?

Comment: Why don't you create `.aws/` config file? This way you don't have to hardcode anything. To access kms, you still need aws credentails.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for example you can explore to use AWS STS to get temporary credentials or use Cognito identity pool to configure identities and use access tokens to access the resource without using access key secret keys. Sharing few links below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorials.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abTy-Yyo6lI